# Endgame Databases

Tags: endgame, database, study

I am looking to practice endgames against a computer by having a decent number (lets say 500+) of positions loaded into a database. Currently I am taking positions from various endgame books as well as positions found online and inputting them one by one. I am wondering if such a database already exists online. I want to be able to load a random endgame position from this database, and be able to quickly play against the computer.

If there are good, free online resources to do this I would be happy to hear them as well. I know [Chess Tempo](http://chesstempo.com) has endgame practice but I don't like that I can only do 2 positions a day.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Chessgym](http://www.chessgym.net) allows you to train a number of positions, without registration or a daily limit.

Comment: Nice website. A little slow to respond, but looks good!